# i did not factorial in this autolisp

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

I try to factorial for in this code but, I did not get the answer.

```
  (defun fact(n)

  (if (= n 0)

    (setq n 1)

    (setq pr (* n ( fact (- n 1))))
        
    (print pr)

    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are supplying too many arguments to the `if` expression in your code. An `if` statement will accept at most 3 arguments:

1. A test expression
2. A 'then' expression
3. An optional 'else' expression

In your code, you are supplying **4** arguments:

1. `(= n 0)`
2. `(setq n 1)`
3. `(setq pr (* n ( fact (- n 1))))`
4. `(print pr)`

You are also missing a closing parenthesis.

To correct your code, the final `print` expression can be moved outside of the `if` expression, and the `pr` variable should be declared as a local variable i.e.:

```
(defun fact ( n / pr )
    (if (= n 0)
        (setq n 1)
        (setq pr (* n (fact (- n 1))))
    )
    (print pr)
)
```

However, whilst the code is syntactically correct, you will now receive the error:

> ; error: bad argument type: numberp: nil

This is because, when `n` is 0, the variable `pr` is not defined and so the `print` expression will return `nil`, causing the multiplication with the return of the recursive call to fail.

However, whilst the code could be modified to define `pr` when `n=0`, this variable is not actually required, and the code may become:

```
(defun fact ( n )
    (if (< 0 n) (* n (fact (1- n))) 1)
)
```

The function will now return the value of the calculated factorial:

```
_$ (fact 5)
120
```

Comment: thank you so much lee mac for your reply.I have learned from your website.; lot of thanks to you.

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark the answer as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate), so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unsure how to do this. Thanks!